# HTML, CSS and Responsiveness not being 'responsive'

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Weird issue. I'm designing a website and have come across the issue that alignment and general positioning messes up on mobile.

I've designed a simple box with another 2 boxes inside. Inside the red box, as you see below, there's a letter which is both vertically and horizontally centred, however, this is not the case on my Galaxy S5 which shows it a bit off. Why is this? Surely it isn't a CSS issue rather a Android WebView issue but it works on an S3 mini just as it should. What am I missing? (The default browser shows the website just fine, it's just the WebView that's messing up).

[Macbook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK75X.png)

[Galaxy S5 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm77Y.png)

Comment: We won't be able to tell if you don't post any relevant code. We cannot guess what your markup and styles are.

Comment: Some CSS features may not be supported in the webview. Other centering techniques might work in both: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The viewport meta tag in the head of your HTML will tell the device to display the page at the width of its own screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```